# How to get the image of dynamic html element in Extjs

Tags: html, extjs

I have a portal (attached image) in which when I click a button I get some images in a panel (right side). Now I want when I click on each of this image to get an alert box with the image id. How can I access this? Till now I have done everything using jquery and now I am in the process of migration. This is part of my code:

```
           items: [{
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                width: 600,
                activeTab: 0,
                flex: 2,
                layout: {type: 'fit'},
                items: [{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'Images',
                        items: [{contentEl:'img',autoScroll:true,height:500 }],

                 },{    
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'Material',
                        items: [{contentEl:'msg',autoScroll:true,height:500 }]
                        }]
            }]..
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add listener to an image element, when you append it

```
{
    xtype: 'image',
    src: 'some-path',
    listeners: {
        el: {
            click: function() { alert(this.id); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also try to catch click event from controller